# I am trying to figure out how to create a Fan shape background for FAB menu

Tags: android, android-background, floating-action-button

I have added a dimmed background for FAB menu in Fragment Navigational Drawer.
I would like to have a fan shape background like

[image]

this. Can some one please help me on this.

till now i have tried this but shape is not proper.

```
ArcShape shape = new ArcShape(90, 180);
        ShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(shape);
        shapeDrawable.getPaint().setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));
```

Comment: What is wrong with the shape that you get? It seems like your startAngle and sweepAngle might need to be adjusted based on the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape.html). I was thinking you might need to use new Arcshape(0, 90) based on the screenshot, but it would be nice to know the exact problem.

Comment: actually the problem is with arch shape is 0 degree of startAngle is center of the screen. but i want my background to be start from bottom right off the screen to become background of FAB arc menu. new Arcshape(0, 90) is just reverse of what i needed

Comment: "0,90 is reverse of what you need"; that should be the clue. But you can be lazy, only 4 quadrants to investigate; why dont you try all 4 for an experiment? (fwd and back, only 8 combos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this issue by making a drawable as fan in background of linear layout